# Do Hierarchical Data Template need INotifyPropertyChanged on property's property of observable collection type

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have simple example, in which code behind is like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication7
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonBase1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Items.Add(new Item() { ItemName = DateTime.Now.ToString(), SubItems = new ObservableCollection<string>() {"1"} });
        }

        private void ButtonBase2_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var f = Items.FirstOrDefault();
            if (f!=null)
                f.SubItems.Add(f.SubItems.Count.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> SubItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and XAML is like that

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"></TextBlock>
                   <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"></TextBlock>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Click="ButtonBase1_OnClick">321</Button>
        <Button Click="ButtonBase2_OnClick">123</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

It is still not clear for me why the behaviour is different - ListBoxes are updated with every little change in both collections (as supposed for ObservableCollection). But **in TreeView only the first level is updated correctly while the sublevel is constantly emty**. If I add INotifyPropertyChanged to SubItems Property the sublevel of TreeView also is updated correctly. Can anybody tell me about that?

Answer (score 0):

When your window opens, it begins to process all the data from `Items` collection. Once finished, there is no way apart of some kind of notification on Items' change for window to see that data have changed and content is to be updated. So, for help here come `INotifyPropertyChanged` and its cousin, `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

You may also consider resetting ListBox.`ItemsSource` to null and back to Items - this will effectively make the control to re-process the data and re-render contents.

Comment: Hi, Alex. The question is why ListBoxes are updated correctly without additional INotify while  TreeView updates only the first level but not the sublevel in this case. So ListBoxes behaviour is correct and supposed to be like this. But the TreeView behaviour is strange.

Comment: @Kehel, I spend some time with your sample in VS2013 and got quite lost :( When I click 321, both TreeView and List gets one item added, and TreeView has arrow on the left showing that there is something on second level. Then click 123, and I have two items in the nested listbox *as well as two items in the TreeView's expandable rows*, which are *not expanded by default* so it looks as TreeView wasn't updated. So everything works fine for me. Would you please add some screenshots showing what you have and highlight what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: Very strange, maybe it all because of VS2015... I should check it in VS2013

Answer (score 0):

Check on VS2013 and one more time on VS2015, can't repeat the problem in the description. Suppose that it was some outer condition, not code.
Anyway thanx to @AlexSeleznyov for conversation =)